# create a json string in perl

Tags: json, perl

I am trying to create a json string in perl that outputs something like this:

```
{"d":{"success":false, "error":"key is required"}}
```

I have figured out how to do it without the "d" using this example:

```
my %rec_hash = ('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
my $json = encode_json \%rec_hash;
print "$json\n";
```

but not sure what I'm suppose to do with the extra level

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you need is a [hash reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

my $json = JSON->new;

my $data_to_json = {d=>{success=>JSON::false,error=>"key is required"}};

print $json->encode($data_to_json) . "\n";
```

The output is:

```
{"d":{"success":false,"error":"key is required"}}
```

Note the use of `JSON::false` to denote a value that the `JSON` module will correctly translate to `false` as a JSON value.

Comment: oh that's very simple I seem to have been going about it the wrong way. Thank you.

Comment: @BluGeni - No problem. If you haven't already, I'd consider looking through `perldoc perlref` (which is linked in the answer above). Perl's most frustrating feature is that data structures automatically flatten unless you use references (which are sorta like pointers, except not useful save for a workaround to nested data structures and passing by reference).

Comment: @JackManey "...sorta like pointers, except **it's a lot harder to shoot yourself in the foot with them**.) Fixed that for you.

Comment: @AaronMiller - LOL. Fair enough.